# How to download a binary file from Google Drive using C#

Tags: google-drive-api

I am using the v3 .Net Google Apis.  This seems like it should be a simple task, but nothing I have tried seems to work.

I am able to get the file resource for the file I want by doing this -

```
    var fileRequest = service.Files.Get(fileId);
    fileRequest.Fields = "*";
    var fileResponse = fileRequest.Execute();
```

But then I have not been able to actually find a way to download the file.  If I use this -

```
    var exportRequest = service.Files.Export(fileResponse.Id, fileResponse.MimeType);
    exportRequest.Download(stream);
```

It returns a 403 Forbidden status with a message stating that Export is only for Google docs.

I've tried this -

```
    var downloadTask = exportRequest.MediaDownloader.DownloadAsync(@"https://docs.google.com/uc?export=download&id=" + fileResponse.Id, file);
    downloadTask.Wait();
```

But that just returns the markup for the page for the user to login.  I created the export request using a service account so login should not be required.

Any have a sample of doing this in .Net using the V3 google API?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I literally got this to work 5 minutes after posting this.  Here is what I found works (I know I tried this before and it did not work, but who knows) -

```
        public static async Task DownloadFile(string fileId, DriveService service)
        {
            var fileRequest = service.Files.Get(fileId);
            fileRequest.Fields = "*";
            var fileResponse = fileRequest.Execute();

            var exportRequest = service.Files.Get(fileResponse.Id);

            //you would need to know the file size
            var size = fileResponse.Size;

            var file = new FileStream(fileResponse.Name, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite);
            file.SetLength((long)size);

            var response = await fileRequest.DownloadAsync(file);

            if (response.Status == Google.Apis.Download.DownloadStatus.Failed)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Download failed");
            }

        }
```